# Hide Element on onepage-scroll.js site

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, hide

right now I'm building a site using Pete R.'s 'onepage-scroll.js' plugin you can find 
[HERE](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll).
I'm also using Bootstrap and what I want to do is hiding bootraps horizontal nav-bar when on the first 'site' and show it on all the other 'sites' (by sites I mean the different sections this plugin uses). My first idea was to create something like a .hideit css-class and tell jQuery to overwrite it whenever the visible section is not the first, but after trying it for hours I can't find the solution - hope you can help me!

Comment: Could you setup a jsfiddle for that?

Comment: Yeah, sure, I will do this!

To break the whole problem down a bit: 

I have, lets say, 4 sections on this page. When section-1 is visible I want to hide the navbar. When sections 2 - 4 are visible the navbar has to be visible.

Comment: Setting up a fiddle right now, just give me a second. Have a look at it here: http://jsfiddle.net/mleyendecker/VYca5/5/

Comment: seems like jsfiddle doesn't like the plugin, but you can find the fiddle at the link I pasted before